# Should not we increase the minimum reputation requirement to review suggested edit?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, suggested-edits

I often fall in such types of embarrassing situations. It thought to write it before, but did not write for my laziness.

However, all of you know that, a new user, with reputation point 1, can review suggested edits of his own question.

But most of these new users do not know that when a suggested edit should accept and when should reject.

Yesterday, I have suggested [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/10380244) edit, but the user rejected it though a user approved it getting from the review queue. I know there still have some scopes to edit this to make the question better, but I concentrated on showing the image as the user has not enough reputation to add image.

In my guess, the user was a little bit angry because of getting downvotes from the community and that's why he rejected it (see [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33989768/trying-to-help-fix-lolblender-unicode-problems#comment55768423_33989768)) or he completely does not know what he has done.

Most probably the user does not know what is suggested edit. Because, he chosed *Reject and Edit* and added another information.

So, **I strongly want to raise my hand to increase the minimum reputation requirement to review suggested edit.** It could be 15 or it could be 50 whatever you want.

I know it is difficult to add the feature, because some issues would come like:

- If the author wants to edit his question when a suggested edit is in the review queue, then what action should be performed?

But you know these issues are minor and could be solved easily.

Comment: Even if he can't review them, he'll still be able to rollback the change, so your Feature Request won't help... That simple fact counteracts your request, and make all the issues that would come up way too complicated for what basically ends up being a non-feature

Comment: @Patrice At least it would help the editor to get rid of increasing a `edit suggestions rejected`. However, I think the OP could not realize that he could not add the image again until he get the required reputation! But if this feature comes, then he might be able to rollback to the revision where the image was embedded in the question.

Comment: ... who cares for an "edit suggestions rejected" in your profile? It isn't a mark of shame, and I don't think anyone gives a flying f about it honestly.... And if your feature comes, he'll still be able to rollback to 1st revision, so it doesn't change anything in the end. If he wants to mess up, he will mess up....

Comment: @Patrice Oh! I was kidding, though it is an important thing to me to have more `rejected`! But I think real life is different. A user would not be notified to do rollback. But for suggested edits, he is notified, so he opens the notification and does whatever he wants. And if you think more practically, it is not that easy to find the rollback option for a new user. At least I could get it very lately when I was new to the community.

Comment: my point is that if the OP doesn't want your edit, he will find a way to roll it back. The fact some members don't know of the feature to rollback is inconsequential here. If someone sees your edit and goes "hell no!", then what is the difference? He'll look it up, come to meta, ask, get told "you can rollback", and he'll rollback. Suggest an edit, if OP rejects it, comment to him and educate him.... same thing, no? I honestly fail to see a benefit to this.

Comment: @Patrice Obviously different people could have different thinking. But I raised hand to reduce the massacre in the questions in the community. However, Look at the rollback process you describe! How long process to get learned about rollback! You are telling to educate him, but people rarely comes back to see whether his edit is accepted or rejected!

Comment: @Patrice "if the OP doesn't want your edit, he will find a way to roll it back" -- I really agree with you, but "if the OP could not realize that what he is going to do"  then? Most of the new user does not realize that he need a certain reputation to add image. But, if he rejects once, he could not get it. If he could not reject, others would accept it. Then he has both options.

Comment: @manetsus and for every low rep user who rejects it because he is uneducated about the site, you probably have another user who is familiar enough with the site to understand what the edit is trying to do.  You want to prevent those users from approving edits to their own posts?

Comment: @psubsee2003 If a low rep user knows about commenting properly, then why he should wait for having 50 reps?

Comment: @manetsus low rep users can comments on their own posts.

Comment: Most importantly, the post has their name on it.  It would be bad to misrepresent the OP with a bad edit.  Some things only the OP will be able to determine whether the edit is in line with their intentions.  That's why they have veto power over everyone without a diamond.

Comment: The op has binding edit privileges over their own post, why would not allowing them to review suggested to their own post be a good thing? that's a learning tool. they can see what changes can be made to their post to potentially make it a better one.

Comment: @ryanyuyu "Some things only the OP will be able to determine whether the edit is in line with their intentions" -- If it is, then there is no need of suggested edits in review queue, because, every OP has an OP. However, don't want to argue.

Comment: @psubsee2003 but comments have no review queue!

Answer (score 6):

**No we should not**. Doing that doesn't make sense because we would then have these users coming to meta to complain about not being able to reject horrible edits on their posts that are subsequently robo-approved in the suggested edit queue.

I don't see a problem with the system the way it is in this regard, I would advise that in situations like these you just move on and do something else.